# HERE Maps - Can you view traffic from further zoom?

Tags: javascript, here-api

I am currently working with HERE Maps API and I currently have a traffic toggle up and working. The problem I am having is that when I toggle on the traffic layer using [this](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/3.1.14.0/dev_guide/topics/traffic.html) method it seems to not render. I have to zoom in quite a bit on the map to actually see the traffic layer get rendered in. Is this how it is designed or is there a way to view traffic from a further zoom level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With H.ui.ZoomControl.Options, default zoom level while rendering for a map can be changed. If you think that you really need to zoom a lot after the traffic layer gets loaded, you can optimise using that. After that, can set zoom_min and max value to further check the traffic details in the map.

Please refer following link to further check for zoomcontrol options > 
https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/3.1.14.0/api_reference/H.ui.ZoomControl.html